# Android Webview app can’t process payments through PayPal on Opencart site

Tags: android, paypal, webview, android-webview, opencart

I made a Android app called Speedway Groceries. It is a Webview app that connect users directly to the Speedway Groceries Opencart website. Although the app works well enough with the website, the problems start with the checkout process. Users can't seem to finish there payments on PayPal. Whenever they do they keep getting the message "We're sorry Things don't appear to be working at the moment." message from PayPal and I need some insight on what might be going on.

Also, I am using Bitnami Opencart on Google Cloud Platform for hosting the website. The version of the I am using for the site is Openart is 2.1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Chrome custom tabs. Can you test it and get back to me?
[How to use chrome custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)